# print content of configuration file on php

Tags: php

How do I have a simple php script that takes input from a configuration file.

```
-
```

The content of configuration file:

```
values.conf:

['abc.net | 5,20,35,50', 'def.net| 5,20']

-
```

The content of php script:

```
foo.php:

require values.conf

echo abc.net
5
20
35
50

echo def.net
5
20

-
```

Comment: there are many ways ,include(), file() ,file_get_contents()

Comment: hi,can you show in code? I am new to php. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement some sort of parsing on your custom config file if you need to, although I would recommend to use a standard format, such as JSON, php itself, yaml, xml (ordered by my personal preferences)

A possible piece of PHP code to parse your input would be:

It needs to be in the same folder than your "values.conf" file that you are trying to import.

```
<?php

$config_file = file_get_contents('values.conf');
$parsed = explode("'", $config_file);
foreach ($parsed as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 === 1) { // only use 1, 3, 5...
        $var = explode("|", $value);
        $config_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $var[0]);
        $config_value = explode(",", preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $var[1]));
        $config_imported[$config_name] = $config_value;
    }
}
```

At this stage your config file will have been parsed and its contents will be in the PHP variable $config_imported looking like this:

```
      var_dump($config_imported);
      //array(
      //     "abc.net" => array(5, 20, 35, 50),
      //     "def.net" => array(5, 20)
      //);
```

You can then define a "print" function that will do:

```
      function config_print($var) {
          foreach ($config_imported[$var] as $item) {
              echo $item . PHP_EOL;
          }
      }

      config_print("abc.net") will write what you described.
```

Comment: hi, how do i import that configuration file, and where should it be kept?